# Why does this Iterator infinitely loop?

Tags: scala, mutability, pass-by-name

I'm attempting to chain `Iterators`:

```scala
var it = Iterator(1)
it.next
it = Iterator(2) ++ it
it.next
it.hasNext
```

This infinitely loops on the `hasNext` as you can see here: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qbHIVfsFSNO5OYmT4pkutA

If you run this and inspect the stack while it's infinitely looping, it's looping in the concetentation:

```
        at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.merge(Iterator.scala:213)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.advance(Iterator.scala:197)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$ConcatIterator.hasNext(Iterator.scala:227)
```

(This stack is from Scala `2.12.11`, but the Scastie link shows same behavior in `2.13.2`).

I know that *one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it*, but this appears like it would work to me. Using the `var` to point to the "current" Iterator and changing it to point to a new Iterator that appends the remainder of the previous one.

The following slight modification does work:

```scala
var it = Iterator(1)
it.next
val x = it
it = Iterator(2) ++ x
it.next
it.hasNext
```

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1X0jslb8T3WIFLHamspYAg

This suggests to me that somehow the broken version is creating an Iterator that is appending itself. Any hints as to what is going on here?

Comment: In conclusion, mutability is bad.

Comment: No disagreement here. I'm benchmarking this vs. functionally pure code and will pick the latter if possible. Only issue is this is performance critical code so it's a reasonable candidate for mutation under the hood if it runs really fast. Amazing how much confusion there can be in 5 lines of imperative code though...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument to the `++` method of `Iterator` is passed by name. `++` returns a new `Iterator` that just stores a function which returns `it`, but doesn't call it until you try to use the appended elements.

So `++` tries to evaluate the argument only when you call `it.hasNext`, but by that time `it` is already redefined as the result of `++`, so it ends up trying to append `it` to itself.

In other words `var`s and by-name parameters don't work together.

So don't reassign `Iterator` method results to the same variable and give them new names instead:

```
val it = Iterator(1)
it.next
val it2 = Iterator(2) ++ it
it2.next
it2.hasNext
```

Comment: I had no idea that by-name would capture the actual `var` as opposed to just the object it's pointing to but it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @JackKoenig Yes, pass by-name creates a closure, and closures do see changes to `var`s in scope. Consider that for example: `def make(): () => Int = { var i = 0; def result() = { i += 1; i }; result }; val f = make(); println(f(), f(), f())` will print `(1,2,3)`